# How to build without make clean after making changes in dts with AOSP?

Tags: android, makefile, kernel, android-source, device-tree

I made few changes in dts and when i gave `make -j8` from my `aosp-root-directory`, I don't see the changes taking place after building it and booting up my board. It just quickly builds in a minute or so. For the changes to take place, i had to give `make clean`.

Giving make clean takes about 4 hours. Do i have to give make clean everytime i do any changes in my build/dts or can we somehow just clean kernel and build it without cleaning the whole `OUT` directory?

Answer (score 3):

To enforce the changes and make sure that they are present in the images, I manually remove the system and vendor images before make:

```
find ./out -name vendor.img -delete -o -name system.img -delete
```

and then do make:

```
make -j8
```

Comment: But i don't think if i make changes in kernel, system and vendor img changes, right?

Comment: I didn't try with changes in dts, but you can try to experiment with deleting  ```dt.img```, ```boot*.img```...

Answer (score 2):

In most cases the changes should be picked up by the build system. But to be sure and keep build time a bit less, you can use `make installclean` instead of `make clean` and build again.

Also, consider enabling compiler cache (ccache) for speeding up subsequent builds.

Check the flags for ccache here:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/core/ccache.mk

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following options:

1. Recommended method would be to use `make installclean` and then `make -j32`. `installclean` will clear only the relevant output files.
2. dts files are compiled using dtc compiler to a format called dtb. Remove the relevant dtb file in kernel folder and rebuild. dtb files are usually integrated to boot.img. So delete all boot.img in /out and /kernel folder.

   `find out/ kernel/ -name boot.img | xargs rm`

Second method would be more faster in this case. But a cleaner method would be the first method.

`make clean` wipes out the entire /out directory which will increase the build time than `make installclean`. Build time also depends on the host machine capability.